# Equivalent of SQL Servers's STUFF and XML PATH in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have an SQL Server database that I want to convert/migrate to MySQL.

I am getting the error message below.

> Error Number: 1064
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') FROM (SELECT a3t' at line 10

```
SELECT DISTINCT task_id, members = STUFF(( SELECT N', ' + t.Ful FROM (SELECT teamAlpha.task_id, ( users.firstname   + ' ' + users.lastname ) as Ful FROM teamAlpha JOIN users ON users.user_id = teamAlpha.user_id ) t WHERE t.task_id = u.task_id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') FROM (SELECT teamAlpha.task_id, ( users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname ) as Ful FROM teamAlpha JOIN users ON users.user_id = teamAlpha.user_id ) u
```

Here's the code:

```
    $query = $this->db->query("
 SELECT DISTINCT
 task_id,
 members = STUFF((
      SELECT N', ' + t.Ful
      FROM (SELECT teamAlpha.task_id,
                     ( users.firstname  + ' ' + users.lastname ) as Ful
                FROM  teamAlpha
                JOIN users ON users.user_id = teamAlpha.user_id ) t
      WHERE t.task_id = u.task_id   
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM 
(SELECT teamAlpha.task_id,
         ( users.firstname  + ' ' + users.lastname ) as Ful
    FROM  teamAlpha
    JOIN users ON users.user_id = teamAlpha.user_id ) u");

    return $query->result();
```

What is the equivalent of SQL Server's `STUFF()` and `XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''` in MySQL?

Comment: ROFL. I have never seen anyone ask this question this direction. It is always "how do I create a delimited list in sql server like I can in mysql with GROUP_CONCAT".

Comment: @SeanLange Yes.  Maybe today is Opposite Day on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you just want to generate a CSV list of people associated with a given task across your table.  You may try the following query:

```
SELECT
    ta.task_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS fullname
FROM teamAlpha ta
INNER JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = ta.user_id
GROUP BY
    ta.user_id;
```

Note the ugliness of having to use `FOR XML PATH` disappears.  Though SQL Server has rich support for analytic functions, it's group concatenation support was not so good.  In SQL Server 2017 there is a new function `STRING_AGG` which basically does the same thing as MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`.